# cant get rid of file with weird name/encoding on linux

Tags: linux, bash, encoding, sh

I have a file That appears as `? ?` in ls:

```
drwxr--r--    1 johndoe gid-johndoe  93756 Aug 22 09:10 .
drwxr--r--    1 johndoe gid-johndoe 574633 Aug 22 09:18 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 johndoe gid-johndoe 874857 Aug 12 15:25 ? ?
-rw-------    1 johndoe gid-johndoe  96342 Aug 22 08:41 .bash_history
```

When I try to grab the filename with sed, i get this strange output:

```
ls -la | sed 's/.*[0-9] //'

.
..

ash_history
```

I think the filename must have a weird encoding, but I dont know how to get a 'handle on it' so I can open/rename/delete it.

How can I get a handle to this file to open/rename/delete it?

**Edit**

When I type `ls` and hit tab to auto-complete, the file shows up as `^[ ^[`

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/how-do-i-delete-a-file-named-in-bash

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been answered on Unix stack exchange.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hmmm. The accepted answer there is crap. But the second most rated is good.

Comment: The accepted answer there should probably be `rm -i *` to get every file, or `rm -i [^a-zA-Z]`, as suggested by the third answer.

Comment: I like that I can't mark this as a duplicate because of the special charecter in the title of the other one.

Comment: @hek2mgl. I agree about the first answer. The comments for it fix the issues, as do the next two answers. Important thing is that there is a working answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/how-do-i-delete-a-file-named-in-bash) from the comments I found a solution:

1. run `ls -i` to get inode number
2. run `find . -inum <inode> -ok rm '{}' \;` with the inode number to delete with `'are you sure?'` prompt.

Answer (score -2):

```
rm -i "$(ls|grep -E -m1 '\?|[[:cntrl:]]')"
```

be sure to use rm -i to verify matched files - match one at a time - the regex matches a literal questionmark as well as any ? displayed for invisible control characters

tested - created 3 files - with literal ? - with tab between ? - with ESC control characters - use CTRL-V to type control characters in a bash terminal

```
$touch '? ?' '? ?' '^[ ^['; ls -A1
? ?
???
? ?

$rm -i "$(ls|grep -E -m1 '[?[:cntrl:]]')"
rm: remove regular empty file '\033 \033'? y

$rm -i "$(ls|grep -E -m1 '[?[:cntrl:]]')"
rm: remove regular empty file '?\t?'? y

$rm -i "$(ls|grep -E -m1 '[?[:cntrl:]]')"
rm: remove regular empty file '? ?'? y

$ls -A
```

Comment: If the file's name would be really `? ?` then you could simply do `rm '? ?'`

Comment: my technique is more general and can match files with some unprintable or invisible characters

Comment: (1) How does `rm` translate the `?` back then? And (2) how do you distinguish between files which contain the `?` and files which contain non-printable characters? You gave a good example why to output of `ls` should not get piped into other commands.

Comment: this does not work.  Typing `ls|grep '\?'` produces no results.

Comment: then the ? maybe a placeholder for a control character that cannot be displayed - try rm -i "$(ls|grep -m1 '[[:cntrl:]]')"

Answer (score -3):

You should try with find and a regex.

```
 find . -name "*" -exec ls '{}' \;
```

## Find the test:

```
➜  t1 touch \?
➜  t1 ll
total 8.0K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 netsamir netsamir 0 Aug 22 19:02 ?
➜  t1 find . -name "*" -exec rm {} \;
rm: cannot remove '.': Is a directory
➜  t1 ll
total 0
➜  t1
```

## Another solution is :

```
➜  t1 touch "\? \?"
➜  t1 ll
total 8.0K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 netsamir netsamir 0 Aug 22 19:05 \? \?
➜  t1 rm "\? \?"   
➜  t1 ll
total 0
➜  t1
```

Comment: This does not help when he cannot simply copy the file name / enter the file due to non-printable characters from the shell.

Comment: This actually does nothing more than a simple `ls`

Comment: This did actually let me look inside the directory (when `ls *` didn't).  There is a file `fontList` inside that even if I do `ls */fontList` I get `No such file or directory`.

Comment: The problem is the file is not really named '? ?', rather that is what the terminal is showing because I doesn't know how to display the character.

Comment: Then find should work. Move all important files and then use find as above.